# How to combine dep var columns in Stargazer / R

Tags: r, stargazer

I am trying to combine the dependent variable columns for multiple cox hazard models in R/Stargazer. I know the interpretation is not appropriate, but this is merely for publication purposes. An example with mtcars.

```
library(stargazer)
data(mtcars)
outcomes <- c("vs", "am")
predictors <- c("gear", "carb")
futime <- mtcars$qsec

formulas <- expand.grid("Surv(futime,",outcomes,")"," ~ ",predictors," + ","hp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
formula.list <- as.character(interaction(formulas,sep=""))

coef.summary <- lapply(seq_along(formula.list), 
                       function(x) coxph(as.formula(formula.list[x]),data=mtcars))
```

This creates 4 cox models in this example (2 dep outcomes x 2 indep predictors), but my models are larger of about 10 outcomes x 5 predictors. The output of formula.list:

```
> formula.list
"Surv(futime,vs) ~ gear + hp" 
"Surv(futime,am) ~ gear + hp" 
"Surv(futime,vs) ~ carb + hp" 
"Surv(futime,am) ~ carb + hp"
```

The output I get in Stargazer

```
stargazer(coef.summary, omit=c("hp"),ci=TRUE, 
          digits = 2, omit.stat="all",
          column.labels = c("vs", "am","vs","am"),
          type="text")
===========================================================
                       Dependent variable:                 
      -----------------------------------------------------
                         formula.list[x]                   
           vs            am           vs            am     
           (1)          (2)           (3)          (4)     
-----------------------------------------------------------
gear      1.47*       3.34***                              
      (-0.02, 2.96) (1.36, 5.32)                           
                                                           
carb                                 0.40         0.67**   
                                 (-0.27, 1.07) (0.14, 1.20)
                                                           
===========================================================
===========================================================
Note:                           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

But the output I want is a condensed version by each dependent variable.

```
===========================================================
                       Dependent variable:                 
      -----------------------------------------------------
                         formula.list[x]                   
           vs            am               
           (1)          (2)                
-----------------------------------------------------------
gear      1.47*       3.34***                              
      (-0.02, 2.96) (1.36, 5.32)                           
                                                           
carb     0.40         0.67**   
      (-0.27, 1.07) (0.14, 1.20)
                                                           
===========================================================
===========================================================
Note:                           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Again, I understand this is intentionally separated as these are entirely different models, but want this for summary/presentation purposes. I'm *hoping* this can be done without post-processing in html/Latex, but natively in the R/stargazer.

Comment: Since you already know to never do it like this, perhaps you want to check out my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162157/formatting-multiple-models-on-top-of-each-other-in-stargazer you may arrange models with identical dependent variable as "panels" on top of each other.